# How to test the repository?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, git

```
class Tag
{ 
    public Guid Id { get; set; } 
    public Name { get; set; }
}

public abstract class GenericRepo<TContext, TEntity>  : IGenericRepo<TEntity> 
                where TEntity : class, new()
                where TContext : Context, new ()
{
    private readonly TEntity _entity;
    private readonly TContext _context;

    protected GenericRepo()
    {
        _context = new TContext();
        _entity = new TEntity();
    }

    public virtual void Dispose()
    {
        _context.Dispose();
    }

    public virtual void Create(TEntity entity)
    {
        _context.Set<TEntity>().Add(entity);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public virtual void Update(TEntity entity)
    {
        _context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public virtual void Delete(TEntity entity)
    {
        _context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Deleted;
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public TEntity GetById(Guid id)
    {
        return _context.Set<TEntity>().Find(id);
    }
}

public class TagRepo : GenericRepo.GenericRepo<Context, Tag>, ITagRepo
{
}
```

Tag is my entity, generic repo contains the basic CRUD operations. 
Testing the Create method it works ok.

When trying to delete or update i get a null reference exception.

```
public class UnitTest1
{
    TagRepo _tagRepo = new TagRepo();

    [TestMethod]
    public void Test_Method_Delete()
    {
        Tag tag = new Tag()
        {
            Name = "Test tag5"
        }; 
        Tag tag1 = new Tag()
        {
            Name = "Test tag3"
        }; 
        Tag tag2 = new Tag()
        {
            Name = "Test tag4"
        };

        _tagRepo.Delete(GetById(tag.Id));
    }
}
```

tag1 tag2 tag3 are created and exist in the database.

What am i doing wrong? 
Can i please get a solution?

the GUID is configured in another .cs

```
HasKey(key => key.ID);
Property(key => key.ID)
  .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity).HasColumnName("Id");

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ConfigTag());
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't setting the Id property on your tag variable so it surely cannot load it from the database.

Try changing your Test_Method_Delete to the following:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test_Method_Delete()
{
    Tag tag = new Tag()
    {
        Id = Guid.Parse(""), // Inside the quotes use a valid Id from your database.
        Name = "Test tag5"
    }; 
    Tag tag1 = new Tag()
    {
        Name = "Test tag3"
    }; 
    Tag tag2 = new Tag()
    {
        Name = "Test tag4"
    };

    _tagRepo.Delete(GetById(tag.Id));
}
```

Comment: the GUID is configured in another .cs 
 

    HasKey(key => key.ID);
                Property(key => key.ID)                     .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity).HasColumnName("Id");

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
            {
                modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ConfigTag());
                base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            }

Comment: @McCorn but you aren't setting the Id property on your tag, tag1 or tag2 variables in your unit test so how is the GetById method supposed to work? They will all have Guid.Empty as a value which I doubt exists in your DB

Comment: the guid in the database is not empty or null. it has been generated

Comment: @McCorn can you try assigning the Guids that have been generated in the DB to your tag, tag1 and tag2 variables? Because the objects you are initialising don't have the Id set there is no way to uniquely identify the tag you wish to delete

Answer (score 1):

For testing purpose use unit of work pattern with dummy context.
[image]
[Here a good article on asp.net site](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)